# Get file location that opened c# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am trying to make a basic console application (like command propmt)

what im trying to do is (in simple terms) is if i right click a file, lets call it my.file and i click open with and select my console application to run that file. how can i get my.file location.

I have tried everything and searched on the internet and found nothing.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple the file being opened is sent as arguments to the program. So query the args to get the filename

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Returns the path to the file
    Console.WriteLine(args[0]); 
    // Index 1 returns file path, while index 0 returns the executable path
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1].ToString()); 

}
```